# javascript split or regex

Tags: javascript, regex, split

How can I split this string `"q.attributes['case.ticketnumber'].value.keyValue"` so I get an array with these elements?

```
["q", "attributes['case.ticketnumber']", "value", "keyValue"]
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use `String#match` method, with following regex `/[^.]+\[[^\]]+\][^.]*|[^.]+/g`

```js
console.log("q.attributes['case.ticketnumber'].value.keyValue".match(/[^.]+\[[^\]]+\][^.]*|[^.]+/g));
```

[Regex explanation here.](https://regex101.com/r/dE1pZ2/1)

[image: Regular expression visualization]

---

Or use much better regex `\w+(?:\['[^']*'\])?` (***@IsmaelMiguel*** suggested)

```js
console.log("q.attributes['case.ticketnumber'].value.keyValue".match(/\w+(?:\['[^']*'\])?/g));
```

[Regex explanation here.](https://regex101.com/r/dE1pZ2/2)

[image: Regular expression visualization]

---

Or use regex `/\w+(\[[^\]]+\])?/g`

```js
console.log("q.attributes['case.ticketnumber'].value.keyValue".match(/\w+(\[[^\]]+\])?/g));
```

[Regex explanation here.](https://regex101.com/r/dE1pZ2/4)

[image: Regular expression visualization]

Comment: `/AB|A/` can be simplified to `/AB?/`.

Comment: @IsmaelMiguel : wow that would be much better... I will add it